# Как средствами C++ WinAPI и Direct2D создать поле для ввода ввода текста?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, direct2d

Хочу создать свой textBox с нуля на Direct2D, но как он делается я не представляю. С кнопкой все понятно, проверяешь позицию курсора при клике, а как сделать TextBox?

Comment: Если позиция курсора при клике попадает в нужную область TextBox, то ждёшь нажатий клавиш

Comment: Давным давно писал [утилиту](http://sources.codenet.ru/download/1605/qlaunch_tgz.html) Там в исходнике можно найти реализацию однострочного редактора на WinAPI (Внимание: код по ссылке мягко говоря не очень)